# Excel data validation - formula over 256 character limit

Tags: excel, validation

I want to validate that a user has correctly entered a CIDR formatted subnet, such as 192.0.2.0/24. The following formula correct validates this data:

```
=AND(--LEFT(F6,FIND(".",F6)-1)<256,
--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),99,99))<256,
--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),198,99))<256,
--MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),297,99)),1,FIND("/",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),297,99)))-1)<256,
--MID(F6,FIND("/",F6)+1,2)<33)
```

However it is well over the 256 character limit. Is there a more efficient way to validate this in Excel?

FYI, a CIDR subnet is 4 numbers below 256, separated by periods, followed by a slash and then one or two numbers (although followed by two numbers is true in all my use cases)

Comment: You do not need the `IF(` and the `,TRUE)` parts.  The `AND` by itself will return TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Yes, I realised that after I posted it, but still doesn't get me close to 256 characters. :-(

Comment: Did you see my answer below?  It is at 243

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` by itself will return the needed `TRUE` or `FALSE` and the `IF(` is not needed.

Also `TRIM` when using the `--` to convert to numbers is also not needed as excel will ignore the extra spaces on its own.

I refactored the forth to be a little more concise.

This is only 243 characters:

```
=AND(--LEFT(F6,FIND(".",F6)-1)<256,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),99,99)<256,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),198,99)<256,--MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),"/",REPT(" ",99)),297,99)<256,--MID(F6,FIND("/",F6)+1,2)<33)
```

Comment: Alternate: `=AND(INDEX(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F6,".",REPT(" ",99)),"/",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198,297,396},99)<{256,256,256,256,33},))`

Comment: @tigeravatar I do not believe that would work as a custom data validation as it does not allow array constants.  But putting it in a helper column and then using a reference to that may work.